# Python: Button to a new row or arrange buttons vertically

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
import ansa
from ansa import *

@ansa.session.defbutton('Renumber', 'AGA','Renumber')
def renumberAGA():
    print("Button AGA was pressed.")

@ansa.session.defbutton('Renumber', 'AGG','Renumber.')
def renumberAGG():
    print("Button AGG was pressed.")
```

...

And so on..
This puts every 3 button horizontally and the 4th goes to new row. Can I arrange the buttons vertically or somehow put every one in a new row, maybe separate them?
It's a loadable internal script in a program. I've tried guitk but when I use other option on the program, the script quits or crashes the program.
When I resize the window the button arrengement stays.
[image: normal] [image: resized]

Using Ansa Pre-processor on CentOS with Python 2.6.6.

Thanks

Comment: Please, specify more context. What is `a`? What framework are you suing ?
We're not mind readers :/

Comment: Sorry, it's a pre-processing software called Ansa, the a stand for that. Using CentOS with python 2.6.6.

Comment: A good idea is to write the context in the question still, someone who opens your question might disregard comments. And please make more detailed description. Don't expect ppl who come to help to google names for you, provide hyperlinks.

Other than that if the framework/lib is rarely used, there is high chance it won't be answered :(

Comment: Also, if this is a GUI-related question, screenshots help as well a lot

Comment: Thanks. Was not sure, which information is needed. I'm just scratching the surface of python programming. And the code that I'm writing is not for commercial use.

Comment: Please add the images correctly, and add a valid description. Now they are just hyperlinks. Sparing visitors the effort (and potential danger) of opening external links, it is better to include the image. Use the image button in the post editor for that.

Comment: Tried "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: There's very few info about this lib in Google. Try to create a page designed with HTML - it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the order of def button in ANSA while coding in  Script editor. 
You can create a GUI instead, using the Designer Window in ANSA .